# sql server using all the memory on the box and throwing timeouts on pedestrian queries

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, memory

I have max memory set.
But at least 1 time a day the Sql Server hits over 95% of the ram in the box, and page faults for more. In the meantime the website is throwing very obscure timeouts on simple

```
select count(1) where id=1
```

type queries

I'm a developer and don't normally get into the server administration to this level of detail. So please go easy on the level of your answers.

Comment: What is your cost of parallelism configured for (right click on server and hit options)

Comment: The Cost of parallelism threshold is set to 5

Comment: That's normal. What's your max memory set to?

Comment: The max memory is set to 14 GB on a 16 GB box, does it need to be lower?

Comment: My best advice would be to try and monitor what's going on with SQL Server Profiler. It's a program that comes installed with SQL Server that let's you see what kind of queries are hitting your databases. Unfortunately, it's not the easiest thing to just pick up and learn but it might help lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Do you have any heavy SQL server job running during time-out period?  And if so adding `(nolock)` table lock hint would get around the problem

Comment: Do you have any/many exceptionally large tables or indexes that would be too large for memory?  Have you checked the execution plan for the queries in question?